# Is there an std:: implementation of sum update

Tags: c++, std

I was wondering wether there was a function in `std::` (as of `c++11`) to compute 
the sum update operation (or 'rolling window sum'). Because I'm not 
sure how that operation is usually called (and this may be what's preventing 
me from finding it in `std::`) the last line of the small code below does what 
I want (and call the rolling window sum...)

```
const int n=101, m=n/2;
float a3[n];
float aD[m-1];
std::fill_n(array,m-1,0.0f);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    a3[i]=rand();
for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    aD[0]+=a3[i];                   
for(i=1;i<(m-1);i++)
    aD[i]=aD[i-1]+a3[i+m-1]-a3[i-1];  //'here: sum update of a3
```

Comment: Is `aD` a local variable? In that case, `aD[0]+=a3[i];` invokes undefined behavior, because `aD[0]` is never initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard library offers no such functionality. You need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this would help you, but there's [Boost.Accumulators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/accumulators.html) with its [rolling_sum](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/accumulators/user_s_guide.html#accumulators.user_s_guide.the_statistical_accumulators_library.rolling_sum).

Comment: Thanks. It's a good suggestion in general though since Idon't use Bost in the rest of the code, it's probably an overkill for me.